# Checking timestamps in PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

If I have a function in PL/pgSQL that takes in a timestamp, what is the best way to identify whether that date is less than 12 months in the past?

e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION do_something(foo timestamp) ....
    -- IF foo is less than 12 months in the past THEN
    --    do something
    -- END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about intervals on [PostgreSQL doc: Date Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-datetime.html). Use something like:

```
where foo < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '12 months'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, equivalently: age(foo) < interval '12 months'